# Finding depth of a multi-parent hierarchy - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with two columns: mother - node
This table forms the base of a hierarchy. A mother refers to a node.
Every node can have multiple mothers, and every mother can have multiple childs. This is accomplished by multiple rows.
If mother = NULL, then the node is a top level node. There can be several top-level nodes, and a node can be both a top-level node AND a child of another node.
e.g:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES(NULL, 2)
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES(1, 2)
```

Im now building a procedure that will need to know the maximum depth of the hierarchy. Lets say node E is a child of node D who is a child of node C.
Node C is a top level node, and also a child of node B who is a child of node A
Node A is only a top level node.
If we say node A has a depth = 0. Then in this case the depth of node E should be 4.

Does anyone have a clue to how i could build a statement that would find this depth for me?
It would have to find the maximum depth of every node in the table and then return the max value of those.

Thanks!

Using SQL Server 2008 btw.

EDIT:

It is ONLY the absolute maximum depth of the table that is of interest. Not the depth of individual nodes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok. I found a solution.

First i created a temp-table with two extra columns:

```
    CREATE TABLE #ParentChildTempTable
(
    Node NVARCHAR(50),
    Parent NVARCHAR(50),
    Depth TINYINT,
    Measure_Depth BIT
)
```

I'm then setting the depth of true-top-level nodes to 0. False top-level nodes will have Measure_Depth set to 0.

```
    UPDATE #ParentChildTempTable SET Depth = 0 WHERE Parent IS NULL AND node not in 
(select Node from #ParentChildTempTable temp2 where temp2.Parent is not null)

UPDATE #ParentChildTempTable SET Measure_Depth = 0 WHERE Parent IS NULL AND node in 
(select Node from #ParentChildTempTable temp2 where temp2.Parent is not null)
```

I then loop down from the top-level until every node has a depth (expect the false-top level)

```
    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #ParentChildTempTable WHERE Depth IS NULL AND Measure_Depth IS NULL) 
    UPDATE T SET T.Depth = P.Depth + 1
    FROM #ParentChildTempTable AS T 
    INNER JOIN #ParentChildTempTable AS P ON (T.Parent=P.Node) 
    WHERE P.Depth>=0 
    AND T.Depth IS NULL
```

And voila! Max depth is found:

```
DECLARE @MaxDepth INT = (SELECT MAX(Depth) FROM #ParentChildTempTable)
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this, it will find all the bottom levels of the hierarchy

```
declare @mytable table(id int, parent_id int)

INSERT INTO @MYTABLE VALUES(1, NULL) 
INSERT INTO @MYTABLE VALUES(2, 1) 
INSERT INTO @MYTABLE VALUES(3, 1) --*
INSERT INTO @MYTABLE VALUES(4, 2) 
INSERT INTO @MYTABLE VALUES(5, 4) --*

;with a as
(
    select 
       id, 
       parent_id, 
       1 lvl 
    from @mytable 
    where parent_id is null
    union all
    select 
        b.id, 
        b.parent_id, 
        lvl+1 
    from @mytable b 
        join a on a.id = b.parent_id
)
select 
    a.id, 
    a.parent_id, 
    a.lvl 
from a
    left join a b on a.id = b.parent_id
where b.id is null
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: That was an ellegant solution. Worked like a charm!

Comment: But one question. How can i do a select max(lvl) from such a statement?

Comment: never mind. i just got a bit confused there for a second. i can see clearly now :)